# Image Overlay Hover “pointer-events: none;” does not work in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So someone gave me a good solution in making the overlay clickable, but it causes the overlay to expand vertically, breaking the overlay effect in WordPress (although it looks fine in codepen).

I found another solution which was to add `pointer-events: none;` which allowed the overlay to be clickable, taking you to another url. I tried implementing it into WordPress because codepen functions as it should, but to my dismay, it doesn’t work at all in WordPress.

Is there an alternative to make the overlay clickable without expanding the overlay grid or breaking the overlay and texts in WordPress?

The goal is to still keep the text remaining on the image, when you mouse hover, the overlay appears, allowing you to click to redirect to another page.

**CSS**

```
.posts {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.overlay:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="js-masonry">
    <?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>
    <div class="item-masonry overlay">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="posts">
            <p><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a ligula sollicitudin, euismod nibh in, feugiat lectus.</h2></p>
        </div>
        <img src="#"/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no reason that this code wouldn't work in Wordpress, so there is something else in your theme or plugins that is preventing it from working. Without knowing what your WP setup is and what code you are using, we can't tell what that problem might be. You will need to do some debugging to narrow it down, and come back if you have enough information for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. `pointer-events: none;` does work.

If you write normal texts within the box, the entire overlay can be clicked on.

If I want to call the  `<?php the_excerpt();?>`, the entire hyperlink gets called onto the excerpt for some reason. Removing this will allow the entire thumbnail and overlay to hyperlink correctly.

Calling `<?php the_title();?>` and `<?php the_date('m-d-y', '<h2>', '</h2>');?>` works fine.